# bundle dylib with application

Tags: dylib, xcode4.5

I'm running Xcode 4.5 and MacOS 10.7.4 and trying to create a MacOS app for local distribution.

I have a dylib from a 3rd party USB hardware vendor.  Rather than drop this into /usr/lib, I wanted to bundle this with the app.  I have tried all of the methods mentioned here that I could find:

Creating a Cocoa Library target, and using a copy build phase,  setting paths with @rpath and @executable_path and @loader_path ...

Here's what I ran into:

I can get the target app to build to compile and run if the dylib is copied into the same directory as the target app (by setting destination to "Products Directory"), however this only works while the app is running within Xcode.  If I run the app from the finder it still looks for the dylib at /usr/lib.

A caveat when changing the destination setting: any files copied to a location in the previous build are not deleted when you make a change a build again.  This tricked me into thinking a few times that I had a solution when I didn't.

"Library search paths" appears to work as expected when linking, but setting "Dynamic Library Install Name" and "Runpath search paths" don't appear to stop the code from looking in /usr/lib only at run time.  They don't seem to have any effect at all.

So, why would setting those path variables have no effect, and how can I set the run time search path?